# Convert punctuation to space

Tags: regex, string, r

I have a bunch of strings with punctuation in them that I'd like to convert to spaces:

```
"This is a string. In addition, this is a string (with one more)."
```

would become:

```
"This is a string  In addition  this is a string  with one more  "
```

I can go thru and do this manually with the `stringr` package (`str_replace_all()`) one punctuation symbol at a time (, / . / ! / ( / ) / etc. ), but I'm curious if there's a faster way I'd assume using regex's.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
x <- "This is a string. In addition, this is a string (with one more)."
gsub("[[:punct:]]", " ", x)
[1] "This is a string  In addition  this is a string  with one more  "
```

See `?gsub` for doing quick substitutions like this, and  `?regex` for details on the `[[:punct:]]` class, i.e.

```
‘[:punct:]’ Punctuation characters:
      ‘! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { |
      } ~’.
```

Answer (score 4):

have a look at `?regex`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(x, '[[:punct:]]',' ')

"This is a string  In addition  this is a string  with one more  "
```

Comment: This isn't a base R function, so you need to add a reference to `stringr`.

Comment: I was using the fact the OP had  stated that they were using `stringr` and `str_replace_all`. Thanks to @Josh for the relevant edit.